# Detect Wrong Proof by strong induction $a^{n-1}=1$ for all $n$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction, fake-proofs

Obviously there is some error in the steps, but i can't figure it out, appreciate some hint.

We show using strong induction that
$$ a^{n-1}=1 \hspace{1cm} \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$

$$ n=1 \hspace{.5cm} \Longrightarrow \hspace{.5cm} a^{1-1}=1$$

We assume that is true for k with $1\leq k< n-1$, then
$a^{n-1}=\frac{a^{n-2}a^{n-2}}{a^{n-3}}=\frac{1.1}{1}=1$

Therefore by strong induction principle. $\hspace{1cm}a^{n-1}=1\hspace{1cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

thanks

Comment: Hint:  usually these fake proofs go wrong immediately.  $n=1$ certainly holds.  What about $n=2$?

Comment: The induction step would work if $1\leq n-3< n-1$ and $1\leq n-2< n-1.$ The $< n-1$ part certainly works…

Comment: Related: [Questions on "All Horses are the Same Color" Proof by Complete Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428151/questions-on-all-horse-are-the-same-color-proof-by-complete-induction).

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that $n-3\ge 1$ or $n\ge4$. So you need to check for $n=2$ and $n=3$. Clearly, $a^{2-1}=a\neq 1$.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks